# Sort by vote is broken (again)

Tags: bug, sorting

I'm not sure how this relates to [previous bug reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sort%20by%20vote%20%5Bbug%5D), but [since Grace Note asked me to](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11522540#11522540) I'm posting this. Sort by votes is broken on Arqade. On [page 5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?page=5&sort=votes) for instance I see this:

[image]

The last post on page 4 has a score of 0, while the first post on page 5 has a score of 47. I'm using a page size of 50 with no tag ignored or hidden.

<sup>[I blame Grace for not feeding the server hamsters on time](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11522529#11522529)</sup>